# Search best match of an array into a matrix using std::vector

Tags: c++, arrays, matrix, vector

I've just completed a program which does as follows:

- You have `t[10][5]` and `p[10]` arrays.
- You read `dimT` and `dimP`.
- You write `dimT` values in `t[][]` and `dimP` values in `p[]`.

For writing values in `t[][]`, you have to fill lines before. The output must be the column which has highest number of matches for the `p[]` array.
Example:

```
INPUT -> 14 (dimT) 2 (dimP) 0 1 2 3 4 0 2 7 9 1 0 11 12 0 (t[][]) 0 0 (p[])
```

So the final matrix display is:

```
0  1  2 3 4
0  2  7 9 1
0 11 12 0
```

OUTPUT -> The best matching column is 0 with 2 matches (overlap counted).

I created this program using arrays but it's really horrible, so I'm looking for a better and cleaner solution from some experts possibly, using vectors instead of simple arrays.

Comment: can you elaborate further? why do you read dimT and dimP if both arrays already have dimensions? t is a two dimentional array why do you only read one value for its dimension?

Comment: It's an exercise, don't ask me why. I think they want to make it more difficult having a matrix line only partially used (the number "2" in my example if we start from line 0, which has 4 elements instead of the 5 expected). Regarding the 2D array, I just read one dimension since I already know I have to place 5 elements per row (the matrix sizes are already defined also for this purpose). Obviously you can assume that 1<=dimT<=50 and 1<=dimP<=10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my current code. It would be better if I had split it into a function or two more, but it is shorter this way:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

bool IsMatch(vector<double>& col, vector<double>& p, int n)
{
    for (size_t i=0; i<p.size() ;i++)
        if (col[i+n]!=p[i])
            return false;
    return true;
}

int main()
{   
    int dimT;
    int dimP;
    cin >> dimT;
    cin >> dimP;        

    int lineN = (dimT+5-1)/5;       
    vector<vector<double> > t(lineN,vector<double>(5));
    vector<vector<double> > tTran(5,vector<double>());
    vector<double> p(dimP);
    t[lineN-1].resize(dimT%5);          

    //input matrices
    for (int i=0; i<dimT;i++) {     
        double inputVal;
        cin >> inputVal;    
        tTran[i%5].push_back(inputVal);
        t[i/5][i%5]=inputVal;
        }               
    for (int i=0; i<dimP;i++)
        cin >> p[i];            

    //print it out
    for (int line=0; line<lineN; line++){       
        for (size_t j=0; j<t[line].size(); j++)
            cout << t[line][j] << " ";
        cout << endl;
        }   

    //transpose t
    /*vector<vector<double> > tTran(5,vector<double>());
    for (int line=0; line<lineN; line++)
        for (size_t j=0; j<t[line].size(); j++)
            tTran[j].push_back(t[line][j]);

    //output tTran
    for (int line=0; line<5; line++){       
        for (size_t j=0; j<tTran[line].size(); j++)
            cout << tTran[line][j] << " ";
        cout << endl;
        }   
    */

    int maxCol=0;
    int maxMatchN=0;

    for (int col=0; col<5; col++){
        int matchN=0;
        for (size_t j=0; j<tTran[col].size()-p.size()+1; j++)
            if (IsMatch(tTran[col],p,j) )
                matchN++;           
        if (matchN>maxMatchN){
            maxMatchN = matchN;
            maxCol = col;
            }
        }
    cout << "The best matching column is " << maxCol
         << " with " << maxMatchN << " matches (overlap counted)." << endl;
}
```

Comment: I've made an image: http://i.imgur.com/UxbOpIC.png Hope it helps. Also, can I ask you why you are using double Vector instead of int?

Comment: - oh, you want matches in columns, not in lines. Let me try to fix that

- Because you didn't specify the type of numbers. Type double will work for integer input, too, and there was no reason to restrict the input to int. But you can use int if you want.

Comment: It would have been a lot simpler to just store the data transposed the whole time `vector<double> t[5];`.  It is easy to input directly into transposed storage and not very hard to print a non transposed image directly from transposed storage.

Comment: It is also simpler to have the outer dimension as C array rather than vector because the 5 is fixed, and to `push_back` the data as it arrives, rather than decide in advance which "columns" should be short by one.  `cin>>tmp; t[i%5].push_back(tmp);`

Comment: Nah, I don't agree. I don't like using c arrays for most things. Also, transpose-on-input is simpler, but not by much. There are both versions in the code now. As it is, it will transpose on input.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Why did you use a transposed vector? Would you be able to make an explanatory image of the algorithm you wrote?

Comment: Transposing: the IsMatch function must receive a column as a vector, because that is required by your task description. Now, there are other ways to extract a column vector from a 2D vector, but I tought it would be simplest to just transpose the matrix t because then you automatically get all the columns as rows, which are normal 1D vectors.

The algorithm does exactly what you said in the task description. The only quirk is to find a simple way to calculate the sizes of columns(rows). Beyond that, it is a classical find-the-maximum algorithm.

Comment: And - it should be "bool IsMatch", not "int IsMatch". It doesn't make any difference, but bool is nicer.

Comment: Actually your code is too complex for me to understand, but I'm not going to waste your time trying to explain it to me. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simpler (all transposed) version I was suggesting in the comments:  The point I'm trying to show is that the non transposed copy has no value.  You understood it is easier to transpose during input than later.  But you kept the non transposed copy as well, and did the output from the non transposed copy and processing from transposed copy.

Take a look at all the extra nonsense that can be skipped if you don't have a non transposed copy.  Then compare the output loop directly from the transposed copy to the original output loop.  The change to the output loop was trivial and the benefit significant.

```
int main()
{   
    int dimT;
    int dimP;
    cin >> dimT;
    cin >> dimP;        

    vector<double>  t[5+1];  // +1 because empty guard vector makes output loop simpler
    vector<double> p(dimP);

    //input matrices
    for (int i=0; i<dimT;i++) {     
        double inputVal;
        cin >> inputVal;    
        t[i%5].push_back(inputVal);
        }               
    for (int i=0; i<dimP;i++)
        cin >> p[i];            

    //print it out
    for (size_t line=0; line<t[0].size(); line++){       
        for (size_t j=0; line<t[j].size(); j++)
            cout << t[j][line] << " ";
        cout << endl;
        }

    int maxCol=0;
    int maxMatchN=0;

    for (int col=0; col<5; col++){
        int matchN=0;
        for (size_t j=0; j<t[col].size()-p.size()+1; j++)
            if (IsMatch(t[col],p,j) )
                matchN++;           
        if (matchN>maxMatchN){
            maxMatchN = matchN;
            maxCol = col;
            }
        }
    cout << "The best matching column is " << maxCol
         << " with " << maxMatchN << " matches (overlap counted)." << endl;
}
```

That empty "guard" vector is a useful trick to know and in more complicated problems avoids a lot of detail and likely mistakes.  In this code it just saved needing `j<5 &&` in one spot.